# How Did They Do This Graph on This Webpage?

Tags: d3.js, graph, charts

First: This is a brilliant website: http://www.r2d3.us/visual-intro-to-machine-learning-part-1/

Second: I'm trying to reverse engineer how they did the graph under "Making Predictions" (the one with the falling balls and tree chart). At first I thought it's D3 but looking around, I didn't see anything to indicate it is. Plus, I'm wondering how they made the balls follow the path.

Can someone please walk me through the process of creating that graph? I'm trying to learn visual data design and have quite a way to go :)

Comment: If you look at the source code, its underlying js is d3js.

Comment: I just saw that and went to edit my question, but now that you've pointed out my overlook, I'll leave it up! Still interested to see how others would construct it. It's beautiful and I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Link animation motion to the `scrollTop` property of the DOM.  There are two chunks of code that makes this work.  An event handler that records scroll position:

```
container
  .on("scroll.scroller", function() {
    newScrollTop = container.node().scrollTop
  });
```

And then the render code:

```
var render = function() {
  // Don't re-render if scroll didn't change
  if (scrollTop !== newScrollTop) {
    // Graphics Code Goes Here
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(render)
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(render)
```

For more information on this technique, I highly recommend the following link, which was written by the author of the link OP has shared:
https://bl.ocks.org/tonyhschu/af64df46f7b5b760fc1db1260dd6ec6a